# Cannot convert from interface to class

Tags: c#, class, interface

I had an error in my method when I try to add to the database my interface and it gives me the error,

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ForumSite.ActionsAndMethods.Registration.IRegistration' to 'ForumSite.Models.User'.

Here is the code in `IRegistration`:

```
 using ForumSite.Models;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ForumSite.ActionsAndMethods.Registration
{
public interface IRegistration
{
    int UserId { get; }
    string Email { get; }
    string Password { get; }
    string FirstName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
    DateTime Birthday { get; }
    DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    string MobileNumber { get; }
    string Address { get; }
    int UserIsDeleted { get; set; }
    int UserRoleId { get; set; }
    UserRole UserRole { get; }
}
}
```

And this is the code in my model:

```
namespace ForumSite.Models
{
using ActionsAndMethods.Registration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class User : IRegistration
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter Valid Email Address")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "8 to 50 characters only")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Alphanumeric characters only")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "8 to 50 characters only")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Alphanumeric characters only")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "8 to 50 characters only")]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s]+$", ErrorMessage = "Letters Only.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s]+$", ErrorMessage = "Letters Only.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Birthday")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field required.")]
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Numeric input only.")]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field required.")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int UserIsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int UserRoleId { get; set; }

    public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
}
}
```

And lastly, my method which adds the user to my database:

```
using ForumSite.ActionsAndMethods.Registration;
using ForumSite.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ForumSite.ActionsAndMethods
{
public class RegisterAction : IRegistration
{
    ForumDBEntities ent = new ForumDBEntities();
    public void Registration(IRegistration reg)
    {
        reg.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        reg.UserRoleId = 1;
        reg.UserIsDeleted = 0;

        ent.Users.Add(reg);
        ent.SaveChanges();
    }

    string IRegistration.Address { get; }
    int IRegistration.UserId { get; }
    string IRegistration.Email { get; }
    string IRegistration.Password { get; }
    string IRegistration.FirstName { get; }
    string IRegistration.LastName { get; }
    DateTime IRegistration.Birthday { get; }
    DateTime IRegistration.DateCreated { get; set; }
    string IRegistration.MobileNumber { get; }
    int IRegistration.UserIsDeleted { get; set; }
    int IRegistration.UserRoleId { get; set; }

    UserRole IRegistration.UserRole { get; }
}

}
```

I wonder what causes this error?

Comment: While every `User` implements `IRegistration`, not every `IRegistration` instance is a `User`.

Comment: You need to show the line that actually throws the error too

Comment: Could you show us the code where the error occurs too?

Comment: `User` is necessarily an `IRegistration` but `IRegistraiton` is not necessarily a `User`. That's why `IRegistration` exists: Different, unrelated classes can implement it. If you have another class, `CoffeeTable`, which implements `IRegistration`, is every `CoffeeTable` *necessarily* a `User`? Obviously not. Therefore the compiler won't let you make crazy assumptions like that. You're saying "A skateboard and an airplane are both vehicles; therefore, the compiler should assume that every skateboard has four giant jet engines".

Comment: @DavidG you should have that as an answer bro.

Comment: @phuzi, sorry sir. The error occured in the ent.Users.Add(reg) in my Registration class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While every `User` implements `IRegistration`, not every `IRegistration` instance is a `User`.

For example, your `RegisterAction` *also* implements `IRegistration`. So if what you wanted to do was possible, you could, in theory have this code:

```
RegisterAction action = GetRegisterAction();

RegisterAction action2 = new RegisterAction(action);
```

Which means when you come to do:

```
ent.Users.Add(reg);
```

It will fail because `reg` is not a `User`.

You could work around it like this:

```
var user = reg as User;
if(user != null)
{
    ent.Users.Add(user);
}
```

But really you should probably take a look at your structure first as it seems quite odd to be doing this.

Comment: Thank you sir. The code finally worked. But I still had an error about the database saying "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details." :D

Answer (score 0):

You have not told is exactly where you get the compile error but my guess is that it in the line `ent.Users.Add(reg)` in the `Registration` method.

To fix the compile error you should change the argument to the `Registration` method from `IRegistration` to `User`:

```
public void Registration(User reg)
{
    reg.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    reg.UserRoleId = 1;
    reg.UserIsDeleted = 0;

    ent.Users.Add(reg);
    ent.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, this may trigger another compile error further up the call chain if you try to pass an `IRegistration` instead of a `User` to the `Registration` method.

While `User` can (and does) implement `IRegistration` you cannot assume that anything implementing `IRegistration` is an `User`. If your code is based on that assumption you will have to fix that to solve your problem.

Comment: I also tried this code and it worked. Thank you for the help! :D